# HTML Tables side-by-side (need them to stack)

Tags: html, internet-explorer

My tables stack on top of each other fine unless they get 100 or so rows, in which case they align side by side on IE 10. I need them to always stack. They're fine or Firefox and on some installations of IE 10. How to I make them always stack regardless of the browser?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Project 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">
        Test Project 1</h2>
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">
        2013-06-09 10:08</h3>
    <table float="left" clear="left" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="728" style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 12px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">
                    RFI
                    <hr />
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Description
                    <hr />
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Rec&#39;d
                    <hr />
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Due
                    <hr />
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Issued
                    <hr />
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Age
                    <hr />
                </th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
    <table float="left" clear="left" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="728" style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 12px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">
                    CCO
                    <hr />
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Description
                    <hr />
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Rec&#39;d
                    <hr />
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Due
                    <hr />
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Issued
                    <hr />
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Age
                    <hr />
                </th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that empty paragraph beween the tables you could try adding

```
<br style="clear:both"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using float property. You need to break next element to new line ,use:

```
table {clear: both;}
```

or put a `<br/>` tag between tables.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `float="left" clear="left"` attributes on the `table` tags and you will be fine. `float` and `clear` are not even valid properties of tables.

Answer (score 0):

Add both the tables in a table

like

```
      <Table id="main">

   <tr>
    <td>
      <Table id=1> </table>
   </td>
   <td> 
     <Table id=2> </table>
   </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```